# Atalhos - OpenSuse 13.2

Tags: linux, opensuse

Estou querende desenvolver atalhos no linux OpenSuse 13.2.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que ao apertar `super+e`
ele abra os `arquivos`.

Eu sei que para faze-lo necessito ir em `configurações->teclado->atalhos`, mas não sei como proceder a partir dai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode se alterar em `configurações->teclado->atalhos`  na barra lateral esquerda `lançadores`, na lateral direita vai aparecer `Pasta Pessoal` e clicar em cima para alterar o atalho.